How to explicitly mark a package as internal when ordering imports?
I've got this:
"pathGroups": [
          {
            "pattern": "react",
            "group": "external",
            "position": "before"
          },
          {
            "pattern": "{app,components,shared,utils}/**",
            "group": "internal",
            "position": "after"
          }
        ]

it works for the most part but because import from shared like so:
import { Button, Tag } from "shared" it thinks that shared is an external library so it's trying to categorise it in the external deps. Why won't it listen to the pattern above?
I want my order to be, react, external, internal, current dir

To achieve the ordering you want, you can use a combination of pathGroups and paths options in your tslint.json file.
Here is:
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended"],
  "paths": {
    "@shared": ["src/shared"]
  },
  "pathGroups": [
    {
      "pattern": "react",
      "group": "external",
      "position": "before"
    },
    {
      "pattern": "**",
      "group": "internal",
      "position": "after"
    }
  ]
}

Thank you!

Unfortunately that seemed to break all the rules
